# Facebook Graph API Error - App button auto detection is disabled

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I got this in my error log from my app in android studio and I cant figure out what caused this issue.

Have anyone encountered this error before?

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 43003, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#43003) App button auto detection is disabled}
```

Thank you for checking out this post.

Comment: i am also getting the same issue. have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: I was not able to connect my app with the website(Wordpress) after the domain was changed. It was just only loading. After checking I got that it was only SSL issue which was not activated on my domain.